# Modern C++ makes memory leaks harder to find

Tags: c++, unit-testing, c++11, smart-pointers

How are you supposed to test modern C++ for memory leaks?

Out unit test cases typically look like this:

```
TestCase {
  Instantiate testObject
  testObject->AllocateSomeResources
  testObject->PerformATest
  testObject->DeallocateResources
  Destroy testObject
}
```

We use valgrind for detecting memory leaks. This is very effective if the resource allocation is done with `new` and `delete`, but when the resources are stored as smart pointers inside standard containers, the automatic cleanup at testObject destruction prevents us from finding faults.

When the system is live. resource containers may grow over time due to a faulty deallocation procedure. This would have been trivial to find if the allocation was done with `new` and `delete`.

Are there any techniques that will remedy this aspect of modern C++?

Ideas:

- Make all destructors test for allocated resources. This would impact the production code base quite a bit.
- Create more separated and testable allocation and deallocation procedures. Of course, but since we got alot of this "for free" with more traditional C++, i still would like to find alternatives.

Obviously i see a benefit in standard containers and smart pointers, sorry about the click bait header

**Edit**

An example:

```
class A {
  int* resource;
  public:
    void allocate(){ resource = new int; }
    void deallocate(){ /*delete resouce;*/ }
};

class B {
  std::unique_ptr<int> resource;
  public:
    void allocate(){ resource = std::make_unique<int>(); }
    void deallocate(){ /*resource.reset();*/ }
};
```

Both class A and B have the same flaw. A bug in the deallocate function makes them hold memory they don't need after deallocate has been called. With class A, this is an "actual leak" and trivial to detect with for example Valgrind in a unit test. For class B i can only detect the flaw in a unit test by exposing the private resource as public, which i don't want to do. This question is not about Valgrind, but whether there are patterns that will help me to get the same quality product as i would achieve with Valgrind and class A, but using standard containers and smart pointers for storing my private resources.

The involved objects can live for weeks, with a different amount of resources allocated during that time.

Comment: `the automatic cleanup at testObject destruction prevents us from finding faults` - so the actual leak is that `testObject`s themselves are leaking. Surely you cannot find that problem with a test where you create and destroy one manually.

Comment: No, the problem is that all testObject members are automatically deallocated, even with an empty destructor.

Comment: That is what happens with automatically allocated objects, there can be no leak here. Testing for this behaviour is like testing that after `i++`, `i` has indeed increased. It's something the compiler just does.

Comment: In a unit test the testObject is created and deleted, so no leak. But in reality the object is created and is kept alive for weeks, while millions of resource allocations and resource deallocations are performed.

Comment: If destruction of testObject properly releases the resources, then it's not a leak, rather, poor resource management (the resource is freed later than it should), and you should move the respective code to some appropriate method. If destruction of testObject does not release the resources, then the test should detect it.

Comment: I'm tempted to close as too vague. Valgrind is supposed to find actual leaks, like memory allocated via `new` and not deallocated with `delete`. Automatic cleanup is something you were supposed to do anyway, - resources are not free, it is better to release them if they are not needed. How can this possibly prevent valgrind from finding leaks? Can you provide an actual [mcve]?

Comment: So the question is, *Given an object with a related pair of methods, `DoThis` and `UndoThis`, how do I detect code where `DoThis` is called but `UndoThis` is not?* This kind of thing is done with a static code analyzer, but I doubt any of them would be of any help in your case because you want `DoThis` to be called from one method of the parent object and `UndoThis` from another. The analyzer would have no way of knowing that `UndoThis` must be *mentioned in some other method* of the parent object.

Answer (score -1):

You can also test individual methods of `Instantiate` in your unit-tests rather than testing all the methods at once. Run each test independently. Then, you may be able to locate the leaks in each of individual methods.

> Make all destructors test for allocated resources. This would impact the production code base quite a bit
>   Your destructors will be called whenever delete is called or object goes out of scope. It does not seem a need to test them explicitly.